# Can't Figure out why PasteSpecial method of range class failed [Error Code 1004]

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, paste

I am trying to paste data from an other workook to the workbook where I write the macro :

```
Dim excel As excel.Application
Dim wb As excel.Workbook
Dim wb1 As excel.Workbook
Dim sht As excel.Worksheet

Set excel = CreateObject("excel.Application")
excel.Visible = False

Set wbAxes = Workbooks.Open("PATH")

Set wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("PATH")
'wb.Calculate
Set wb1 = excel.Workbooks.Open("PATH")
wb.Worksheets("MySheet1").Calculate

wb.Worksheets("MySheet1").Range("N7:P" & wb.Worksheets("MySheet1").Range("P5").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MYSheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

But I am facing the issue 1004 : "PasteSpecial method of range class failed"

Sure thing is that the data are Copied since when I do "CTRL+V" **it paste data nicely** but the Paste thanks to the macro display

> Error 1004 : PasteSpecial method of range class failed

**EDIT :**

When I try with `.Paste` (Code Below) And not `.PasteSpecial` I got :

> Error 438 : object doesn't support property or method

```
Dim excel As excel.Application
Dim wb As excel.Workbook
Dim wb1 As excel.Workbook
Dim sht As excel.Worksheet

Set excel = CreateObject("excel.Application")
excel.Visible = False

Set wbAxes = Workbooks.Open("PATH")

Set wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("PATH")
'wb.Calculate
Set wb1 = excel.Workbooks.Open("PATH")
wb.Worksheets("MySheet1").Calculate

wb.Worksheets("MySheet1").Range("N7:P" & wb.Worksheets("MySheet1").Range("P5").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MYSheet").Range("A1").Paste

wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: What is the motivation for creating an Excel application from within a running instance of Excel? Why not e.g. simply `Dim wb As Workbook`?

Comment: PasteSpecial does not work (or works differently) for different instances.

Comment: @JohnColeman Because I don't want to get 5 Excel Open And not Hidden. So the created instance is set as not visible and it does not display it on my screens

Comment: @BrakNicku Do you have any suggestion in order to Paste data ? When I try basic `.Paste` I got the error 438 : object doesn't support property or method

Comment: If you need only values you can try using variant array of `Value`. If you want to use PasteSpecial - all the workbooks have to be opened in the same instance.

Comment: In a single instance of Excel you could use `Windows("workbook name").Visible = False` immediately after opening the workbook.

Comment: @JohnColeman Its working now the issue was indeed due to Instance